# How to handle google sign in flow on flask api rest backend?

Tags: android, api, flask, google-oauth, flask-user

### Preface:

I known there are a lot of tutorials and answers about this question but i think there is a bit of confusion. My question is not only about some code but instead on architectural choices

### Context:

We have an android mobile app and a backend API server that store users and some domain model datas. Users can use app without sign in but in this case there is not communication with backend and datas are not stored in DB (through BE)

Suppose we want authenticate user with third party providers (Google, Twitter etc.) only, so we don't have the canonical pair username/psw. In order to keep BE stateless and accessible also from web or other rich/thin clients, i would use tokens to authenticate each request.

I'm following official google documentation https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth but i'm stuck in the last step, when application send tokenId to flask BE. At this point i'm not sure how to complete the flow. I thought

1. check if user email/user_id is in DB
2. If user not in db, save user
3. generate custom jwt to authenticate nexts request

I'm a bit confused, both design and programming aspect, about how store kind of session about user or how refresh custom tokens. Seems i'm missing some step that i can't find on documentations

Answer (score 0):

Googling doesn't helped me.

Currently, the strategy i adopted is

1. get tokenID from android app
2. send tokenID to BE
3. validate user checking if email/account ID is present in db. If User email is not present in DB, register it and in both case generate custom BE jwt token
4. from mobile store access/refresh tokens and use them to authenticate each request

I m not sure if this algorithm is best practice appliance. I would like another opinion about the logic behind the process